# Hide unpublished items from counter in Laravel query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm showing all sub categories under main category. On each sub-category there is a counter of how many items are assigned there.

```
Main Category
   - Sub Category (1)
   - Sub Category (3)
   - etc
```

Current problem is that one item can be published and unpublished. When the item is not published yet I don't want to show it on counter. Column in `items` table is `published` and accept `1` for published and `0` for unpublished.

This is what I have to show them on page

`HomeController.php`

```
$allCategories = Category::where('parent_id', 0)->has('children.item')              
           ->with(['children'=> function($query){
                $query->withCount('item');                    
            }])
            ->get()
            ->each(function($parentCategory){
                $parentCategory->item_count = $parentCategory->children->sum(function ($child) { return isset($child->item_count)?$child->item_count:0;});
            });
```

My Item.php model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

My Category.php model

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item','category_id');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'id', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

I've tried to directly add it to the query but doesn't make any difference

```
$query->withCount('item')->where('published', 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the where condition in the relationship function `item` of `Category.php` model.

Here is the code:

```
public function item()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item','category_id')->where('published', 1);
}
```

Comment: Hm, that was easy. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, quick question regarding this: Is it possible also to hide `childrens` which are empty eg. no item inside

Comment: You can  fetch children where `App\Category` is greater than 0

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I understand. I need to fetch where App\Item is greater than 0

Comment: In that case, you can add another where to `item()` with `category_id` is greater than 0.